# How can I chain search calls using protractor-webdriver js

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

I hope I am phrasing this question correctly.  Basically I'm using a locator to find a group of elements, then I want to find a specific element within that group.

I'm new to async-js and protractor-webdriver, but not new to js (in general) and have some familiarity with other webdriver implementations.  The code will probably be the best way to show what I'm trying to do:

```
var findDatepickerDay = function(month, year, day) {
    var tds = element.all(by.css('.ui-datepicker-calendar tbody td:not(.ui-datepicker-unselectable)'));

    tds.then(function(tds) {
        tds.map(function(td){
            var my= {};
            return td.getAttribute('data-month').then(function (m) {
                my.month = m;
            }).then(function(m) {
                td.getAttribute('data-year').then(function (y) {
                    my.year = y;
                }).then(function() {
                    if (my.month == month && my.year == year) {
                        // console(my); // this returns the anticipated result

                        // a tag contains the day

                        /*td.findElement(by.tagName('a')).then(function(tag) {
                            // findElement is undefined
                        });*/

                        /*td.getDriver().findElement(by.tagName('a')).then(function(tag) {
                            // findElement is undefined
                        });*/
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
};
```

My main question is how do I find an element within the td?

The second question: is there a better approach.  Unfortunately, there are so many implementations bouncing around the web right now it's hard to determine  what approaches 1) works, 2) are current, 3) best practices.  Everytime I run into an issue, I start researching only to find I need to install some new library (my packages list has jump from 3-10 overnight).

I'm using: protractor (2.5.1) which depends on selenium-webdriver (2.47.0)

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be an exact answer, but hopefully will point you in the right direction.  I was working with a table earlier today and needed to grab all `<tr>`'s (rather than the `<td>`'s in your case) under a table.

```
var table = element(by.css('#tableID'));
table.all(by.css('tbody tr')).count().then(function (count) {
        expect(count).toEqual(3);
    });
```

You will want to replace `count()` with whatever you're trying to accomplish.

In your case, you will need to know what type of element tags are under the `<td>` and chain it similarly to what I did above.

```
table.all(by.css('tbody tr td **whatever Element tag**')).then(function() {}
```

As far as chaining, it works with multiple elements and you can do it in one line if you want.  i.e.

```
var something = element(by.css('.parent')).element(by.css('.child')).
```

source: https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.element

Also, since you're using Protractor, it's recommended that you use `element` rather than `findElement` -- `findElement` will return a raw webelement object from webdriver, while `element` will return a protractor version of webelement called an `ElementFinder`.

source: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1008

Comment: Gunderson, thanks for the response.  I tried findElement because element was not recognized.  Whatever type of object td is it didn't appear to be an instance of protractor.  in addition, while I know I can find all td > a tags, what I'm trying to do is find specific a tags based on attributes of the parent td.  I'll keep playing with it using some of your examples.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to the next stage using some of posted suggestions and by moving the filtering into the selector.  I wasn't sure multi-attribute sectors would work with these libraries, but I guess they do.  Turns out I didn't need to do chaining in this instance.

```
var as = element.all(by.css('.ui-datepicker-calendar tbody td[data-month="'+month+'"][data-year="'+year+'"]:not(.ui-datepicker-unselectable) a'));


as.then(function(as) {
    as.map(function(a) {
        var my = {
            month:month,
            year:year
        };
        return a.getInnerHtml().then(function (d) {
            my.day = d;
            console.log(my)
        });
    });
});
```

Thanks for the assistance.